# how to access my form's panel in my class

Tags: c#, class, foreach, panel

I have a form and in the form I have a panel named : mypanel

now I want to write a class and in this class I want to use this:

```
foreach (Control cont in mypanel.Controls)
        {
            // do sth
        }
```

but it is impossible, please help me how to access my form's panel in my class

I use this code :

```
foreach (Control cont in mypanel.Controls)
            {
                if (cont is PictureBox)
                {
                    string path = @"" + Application.StartupPath + "\\Image\\";
                    cont.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(path + Rnd.Next(7).ToString() + ".png");
                }
            }
```

and I have this Error:
**"the name 'mypanel' does not Exist in the current context"**

Comment: Is this class code behind class or some other class?

Comment: no, I just made a class and write a public void start() function and in the Function I write this code

Comment: If you just made another class it has no knowledge of your form or it's contents. You will have to expose the Panel to your class. i.e MyClass.MyPanel = mypanel;

Comment: I think I should use get,set but I don't know how ?!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the type of control is `Panel` and cast it.

```
foreach (Control cont in mypanel.Controls)
{
    if(cont is Panel)
    {
        Panel myPanel = (Panel)cont;
        MessageBox.Show(myPanel.Name);
    }
}
```

You need to cast the control into `PictureBox` since not all control contains the specific property you want to set,

```
PictureBox pBox = (PictureBox)cont;
pBox.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(path + Rnd.Next(7).ToString() + ".png");
```

Comment: when I use this the Error is "the name 'mypanel' does not Exist in the current context"